# Print subset of message

Tags: ros, print, ros-kinetic, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to programmatically print a subset of [this message](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/blob/kinetic-devel/franka_msgs/msg/Errors.msg), specifically only the flags set to true. I have found only [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/50298/get-the-message-definition-in-c/) regarding the display of messages, and the answer suggests to use `ros::message_traits::Definition<franka_msgs::Errors>::value()` which, in this case is a method which returns a long string made like this:

```
return "bool joint_position_limits_violation\n\
bool cartesian_position_limits_violation\n\
...
";
```

Is storing this string and parsing it the only way I can get the names of the errors to use in a for loop that checks which flags are true? Is there no way to get the name of the single error from the message itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306488/print-subset-of-message/) by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 589 on 2018-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
You could take a look at [ros_type_introspection](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection).

Afaik there is no OotB support for this, but that library tries to fill that gap.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-23**:
If you know the message (thus all the fields) maybe you could compare each field in the callback and only print if true like that :

```
if (msg->joint_position_limits_violation)
{
    ROS_INFO("joint_position_limits_violation");
}
//Same for each fields of the message
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:
What @Delb suggests is certainly an approach for this specific message.

I took the question by @aPonza to be a bit more general in which case hard-coding wouldn't be feasible.

**Comment by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) on 2019-01-24**:
If you are still intereste to know the answer, I can write an example for you (I am the author of **ros_type_introspection**).

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2019-01-24**:
I am, I was looking at this question again exactly yesterday to do another similar thing to a message and couldn't remember the name of your package, but in the end delayed the task in favour of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is one of the problems that [ros_type_intorspection](https://github.com/facontidavide/ros_type_introspection) can solve for you.

I created an example here just for you ;)

https://github.com/facontidavide/type_introspection_tests/blob/master/example/franka.cpp

As you can see, you can deserialize **any** ROS message into a list of Key/Value pairs, one for each field of the message.

In your particular case, to keep the example simple, we just used the fact that we know that all the fields are bool.
here you can see an incomplete snippet of the solution:

```
void DeserializeAndPrint(RosIntrospection::Parser* parser,
                         const std::string& topic_name,
                         std::vector<uint8_t> & buffer) {

    using namespace RosIntrospection;
    FlatMessage flat_container;
    parser->deserializeIntoFlatContainer( topic_name,
                                          absl::Span<uint8_t>(buffer),
                                          &flat_container, 100 );

    RenamedValues renamed_numerical_values;
    parser->applyNameTransform( topic_name,
                               flat_container,
                               &renamed_numerical_values );

    for(auto& it: flat_container.value)
    {
        bool value = it.second.convert<int8_t>();

        if( value )
        {
            std::cout << it.first.toStdString() << " : "
                      << it.second.convert<double>() <<  std::endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2019-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2